# Making slider in android using recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, slider, android-animation

How to make a slider like that, i mean to view the previous and the coming item

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRgeu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/yarolegovich/DiscreteScrollView

The library is a RecyclerView-based implementation of a scrollable list, where current item is centered and can be changed using swipes. It is similar to a ViewPager, but you can quickly and painlessly create a layout, where views adjacent to the currently selected view are partially or fully visible on the screen.

I think it will help you.